# Error when config logging use logging.config.dictConfig in python

Tags: python, logging

First of all , I am using python.Try to config logging by a config json file and use **logging.config.dictConfig()** .I used it before and it work well. But this time I delete a little bit and some how it just doesn't work.
My config file will look like this:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(name)-6s | %(levelname)-8s | %(message)s"
        },
        "info_format": {
            "format": "%(name)-6s | %(levelname)-6s | %(message)s"
        },
        "error_format": {
            "format": "%(filename)-8s | %(module)-12s | %(funcName)s | %(lineno)d : %(message)s"
        },
        "debug_format": {
             "format": "%(filename)-8s | %(module)-12s | %(funcName)s | %(lineno)d : %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
             "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
             "level": "DEBUG",
             "formatter": "simple",
             "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
        "info_handler": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "info_format",
            "encoding": "utf8",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
        "error_handler": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "formatter": "error_format",
            "encoding": "utf8",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stderr"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "info": {
             "level": "INFO",
             "handlers": ["console"],
             "propagate": "no"
         },
         "error": {
             "level": "ERROR",
             "handlers": ["console"],
             "propagate": "no"
         },
         "tornado.access": {
             "level": "INFO",
             "handlers": ["console"],
             "propagate": "no"
         },
         "tornado.general": {
             "level": "INFO",
             "handlers": ["console"],
             "propagate": "no"
         },
         "tornado.application": {
             "level": "ERROR",
             "handlers": ["console"],
             "propagate": "no"
         }
    }

}
```

Here is how I config logging:

```
configParser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
__ProjectPath = os.getcwd()
config_path = __ProjectPath + "/configs/logconfig.json"
with open(config_path, 'rt') as f:
    configs = json.loads(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(configs)
```

That is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jonah/code/leancloud-demo/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/jonah/code/leancloud-demo/app.py", line 14, in <module>
    import log
  File "/home/jonah/code/leancloud-demo/log.py", line 51, in <module>
    logging.config.dictConfig(configs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 576, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler u'error_handler': 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I had google for a while,just can not a answer.Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details

```
// class (mandatory). This is the fully qualified name of the handler class

"info_handler": {
    "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
    "level": "INFO",
    "formatter": "info_format",
    "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
},
"error_handler": {
    "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "formatter": "error_format",
    "stream": "ext://sys.stderr"
}
```